# How to test Spring controller with multiple values for produces in RequestMapping Annotation?

Tags: java, spring, testing, content-type

I wanna test a certain controller method, which is serving images to client.
Those images have different content types (jpg, png, gif).

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getImage/{id}/{path}", produces = {"image/jpg", "image/gif", "image/png"})
@ResponseBody
byte[] getImage(@PathVariable("id") String id,
        @PathVariable("path") String path)  {      
    File imageFile = handler.getImage(id, path);
    InputStream in;        
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(imageFile);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How would I write a test, which covers any content type:
my current test:

```
@Test
public void testGetImage_shouldSucceed() throws Exception {
    File testImage = new File(TestConstants.TEST_IMAGE);
    byte[] expectedBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(testImage));
    when(service.getImage(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn(testImage);
    mockMvc.perform(get("/getImage/{id}/{path}", "1L", "bla").sessionAttrs(session))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG))
            .andExpect(content().bytes(expectedBytes));

}
```

How can I use `andExpect(..)` to cover multiple content-types ?
Ideally it should test if the content type is jpg OR png OR gif.

Comment: Either write a separate test for each content type and mock the service to return the correct type of image, or just test the content of the annotation itself.

Comment: I feared that, I had to write multiple tests for this. What do you mean with test the content of annotation ? Could you pls give a short example?

Comment: you can try content negotiation, try `get("/getImage/id/path.jpg")` and `get("/getImage/id/path.png")` and `get("/getImage/id/path.gif")`, then it should return correct format

Comment: I tried that, and actually its working, but i stumbled over a strange issue. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391014/is-produces-of-requestmapping-sensitive-to-order-of-values)